# Why does using two tasks to perform two long computations reduce performance?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am making C# software to implement RFC 1951 "Deflate" compression. When choosing the block boundaries to maximise compression, there is an opportunity to compute the size of two alternative block choices in parallel, to increase performance ( it's  fairly long computation, involving the computation of Huffman codes ).

Here is the non-parallel version:

```
int bits2 = b2.GetBits();
int bits3 = b3.GetBits();
```

Here is the parallel version:

```
Task<int> t2 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew( () => { return b2.GetBits(); } );
int bits3 = b3.GetBits(), bits2 = t2.Result;
```

However the parallel version actually runs slower, and I don't understand why. In case it's relevant, the processor is an Intel Core i7-6700HQ. The complete code is here: https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf/blob/master/Deflator.cs

Why does the parallel version run slower instead of faster, have I made a mistake, and is there anything I can do to make the parallel version run faster than the non-parallel version?

Comment: On my hardware, your `GetBits` method executes in 3µs in average. That's way too short to expect any gain from executing it in parallel. For reference, on that same computer `Task.Factory.StartNew` takes 2µs in average. If you want some gain, you need to divide into bigger units of work

Comment: Thanks Kevin Gosse, I had naively assumed the overhead was negligible ( this is the first time I ever tried using a Task in C# ).

Answer (score 2):

If I run your `GetBits` method on my computer, it runs under 3µs on average. Running code in parallel has some overhead. In fact, a call to `Task.Factory.StartNew` also takes between 2 and 3 µs on the caller side (I didn't measure how long before the task actually starts executing). Therefore, in your case the overhead defeats the potential gain.

That's one of the difficulties of making an algorithm efficiently run in parallel: you need to make sure that the units of work are big enough to counterbalance the induced overhead.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question "is there anything I can do to make the parallel version run faster than the non-parallel version?", I have now re-engineered the code to use two threads - a 2nd thread performs the LZ77 compression - looking for repeated sections of the input which are encoded as a (match-length,distance) pair, while the main thread processes the output of the LZ77 stage ( generating Huffman codes, encoding the input using these codes ).

This has worked out very well, overall it runs about 30% faster, which is very cool.

Threading is very novel for me, I find the code a little scary, I hope I have got my locks and memory barriers right. It appears to be working fine, but I think it's easy to have a hidden concurrency bug that may not show up in testing.

As before, a copy of the code is here:
https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf/blob/master/Deflator.cs